# random number with the gaussian distribution in an interval matlab

Tags: matlab

How can one create an integer random number with Normal distribution in an interval in Matlab? Could anyone provide an answer?

I know how to create a random number ,say y, with Normal distribution:

```
std = 5;
mean = 500;
y = std.*randn + mean;
```

But it is not an integer number and also it is not in a specific interval

Comment: Yes, thats how you do it. What is the question again?

Comment: I want to find "integer" random in an interval, say [a,b]. @AnderBiguri

Comment: Can you then define Normal distribution on integers? I think its not possible...

Comment: "randi" command, fore example: a=randi([a,b], m,n); generate a m-by-n matrix of random uniformly ditributed random number from a to b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want integers, you can use randn and round the numbers. However, your second question is kind of weird.

Normal distribution does not have a definite interval. You can only define a "confidence interval" around the mean. For example, 99.7% of the distribution is contained within 3 standard deviations from the mean. But it does not mean that you have a strict interval, it means probability of seeing a number beyond 3xStandard deviations is just too low. Let's say I generated 10000 numbers with mean=100 and std.deviation=10 and rounded them. Then I expect to see numbers between 70 and 130. There might be numbers beyond this interval, but their frequencies(~probabilities) will be low.

```
mu=100; sigma=10; figure,hist(round(normrnd(mu,sigma,10000,1)),100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Choose the number from a binomial(N, 0.5) distribution for large N. This will yield something that is as close as you might be able to get to a "normal distribution of integers". The mean will be N/2 and the std deviation N/4. Subtract N/2 to center it about 0.

Say N = 100. Then to generate a sample, you could do:

```
k = sum(randi(2, [100,1]) - 1);
```

or:

```
k = sum(rand(100,1) < 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use randn and convert to integer by rounding the output number. Repeat until the number is in range [a,b] you are interested in. 
It will likely work fine for wide enough range around the middle, but you will be doing tons of attempts when you want to look at a narrow part of the tail.

Other option is to get any integer from whatever range with equal probability and convert that to gaussian-like in your range. Say numbers 0->10 would become a, 11-50 would be a+1 ... maxint-10:maxint would be b.